# Work-around for xpdf inability to search for text containing ligature

Tags: ligatures, search

I have a PDF file generated by `pdflatex`.  It contains text such as "third and final reason".  When searching for text like "and final", `xpdf` will not match the "fi".  Based on a foggy memory of having researched this in years (if not decades) past, I assume that this is because of the "ligature" in "fi".  Due to the overhang in "f", that is, "fi" is combined into one symbol to allow for closer spacing (if not overlapping characters).

In my composition/review/revision cycle, the above always throws me for a loop when I quickly try to navigate the document to look for passages.  LaTeX purists would say that I should navigate the source file instead, but for a number of reasons I don't want to go into right now, I often find it better to navigate the PDF (not always).  Many of my LaTeX using colleagues find the same.

Is there a work-around for `xpdf`'s inability to find ligatures?

**Example**

Here is a Minimum Working Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
This is the first and final document.
\end{document}
```

I can search and find `rst`, but not `irst` nor `first`.

Comment: Without a complete example it is not possible to check how the tounicode values in the pdf are in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure if this fills the gap, but I added an MWE.  Hoping that the work-around doesn't involve delving into character codes, but it would be interesting to know how intricate such a solution is.

Comment: Exactly which version of `xpdf` and LaTeX are you using? I just installed `xpdf` (I though that project was dead long ago, I normally use Evince), compiled your MWE using TeXLive 2020, opened the PDF in xpdf searched for `first` no issues

Comment: Try with `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and/or `\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1`

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer: I already have `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but adding `\input{glyphtounicode}\pdfgentounicode=1` solved the posted problem.  Would you mind posting your last comment as the answer?  Thank you!

Comment: @daleif: I'm using Cygwin's `pdflatex`, which soft-links to `pdftex` version `3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Cygwin)`.  I am using `xpdfreader` for Xpdf 4.02 (also from Cygwin). Thanks for the Evince suggestion. Cygwin has that. Quick web search says its a Gnome viewer, but if I run into too many issues with `xpdf`, I'll see if I can run Evince under X-windows alone (no Gnome).

Comment: Evince doesn't need gnome it's just part of the project. It us just strange to me that I needed no extra packages or settings to your mwe. Though I did not catch which xpdf version it was

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and/or

```
\input{glyphtounicode}
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

Comment: Thanks, Ulrike.